# MariaDB on Amazon RDS - Initial setup user grants and permissions

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-rds, mariadb

I'm trying to learn more AWS, and have an EC2 setup and an RDS setup running MariaDB.  When I created the RDS instance, it asked for user/pass for the initial user, and created

```
'rdsadmin'@'localhost' 
'rdsroot'@'%'
```

My guess is that rdsadmin is the default, and rdsroot is what I selected.  I can SSH to my EC2, and from there connect to the RDS using the 'rdsroot' account.  I wanted to create some additional rdsroot accounts with more limited hosts, so did:

```
CREATE USER 'rdsroot'@'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx' IDENTIFIED BY 'a good password';
```

I then did:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON databasecreated.* TO 'rdsroot'@'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

If I do a SELECT user,host I see my new user.  However, when I examine the privileges with:

```
SELECT * FROM information_schema.user_privileges;
```

The only "privilege_type" is "Usage".  When I try to do different grants I get an access denied for 'rdsroot'@'%'.  Since I can't SSH into the RDS instance, and the main default user 'rdsadmin'@'localhost' is limited to localhost, should I / how do I connect as that user so I can properly setup a more restricted sub user?